# Iteration to recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I need some help with a homework. I need to write the following code recursive, but I dont`t know how to do it. Any solution or tip is welcome.

```
def differences(values):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(values) - 1):
        result.append(values[i + 1] - values[i])
        print(result)
    return result


differences([4, 3, 6, 8])
```

The parameter is list of any length with integers.

I tried sth like that, but the output it way too false

```
def differences(values):
    result = []
    if len(values) == 0:
        return
    result.extend(values[len(values) - 1] - len(values) + 1)
    print(result)
    return differences(values[:-1])


differences([4, 3, 6, 8])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. _Specifically_, what does "the output it way too false" mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why did the `.append` call change to `.extend` in the recursive attempt? What effect do you expect this to have? What is the purpose of the `len` calls in there? What exactly do you want this line of code to do?